# Can a noweb block be directed to a specific output block?

Tags: org-mode, tangle, noweb

I know you can give a block the property `:noweb-ref` give it a reference name like `foo` and then in another noweb block you can refer to the reference block with `<<foo>>`. However this means that for every block tagged with `:noweb-ref` I then need to add a line to the target block. Is there anyway of of telling the reference block its target instead? For example, it might look something like:

```
#+begin_src :noweb yes :noweb-ref target-block
Check out this awesome list:
#+end_src

#+begin_src :noweb-target target-block
- one
#+end_src

#+begin_src :noweb-target target-block
- awesome
#+end_src

#+begin_src :noweb-target target-block
- list
#+end_src
```

And this would tangle to:

```
Check out this awesome list:
- one
- awesome
- list
```